# How in Drupal 8 add ckeditor on block? no form

Tags: twig, ckeditor, drupal-8

I have custom module Block with template file.

How can I add simple ckeditor in twig template?

I already added library dependes in module.library.yml

```
table:
dependencies:
- core/ckeditor
- ckeditor/drupal.ckeditor
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of block with WYSIWYG

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "content_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("content_block"),
 *  category = @Translation("content_block")
 * )
 */
class ContentBlock extends AbstractWebConfigurableBlock {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return [] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['title'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['title'],
      '#maxlength' => 50,
      '#size' => 50,
      '#weight' => '1',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#title' => $this->t('Content'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['content'],
      '#format' => 'full_html',
      '#weight' => '2',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];


    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configuration['title'] = $form_state->getValue('title');
    $this->configuration['content'] = $form_state->getValue('content')['value'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    return [
      'title' => [
        '#markup' => $this->configuration['title'],
      ],
      'content' => [
        '#markup' => $this->configuration['content'],
      ],
    ];

  }

}
```

Comment: is there way to do it without form?